# How to create interceptor for apisauce?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I use apisauce for HTTP work of my React application, also I use React-router and Redux Saga.

I have a question do we have a way to create an interceptor in apisauce, and is it possible to redirect there our application to /login route?

I added monitor, this is a feature of apisauce, but I don't have any idea how to redirect there my app to /login route.

Thx for your help.

Example of my monitor:

```
constructor() {
  this.api = apisauce.create({
    baseURL: env.API_URL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user') || ''}`,
    },
    timeout: 15000,
  });

  this.api.addMonitor(this.tokenMonitor);
}

private tokenMonitor(response: any) {
  const { ok, status } = response;

  if (!ok && status !== 200) {
    // I should do redirect here
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

maybe you can use, something like this:

```
constructor() {
  this.api = apisauce.create({
    baseURL: env.API_URL,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('user') || ''}`,
    },
    timeout: 15000,
  });

  api.axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use(
    (config) => {
      const token = JSON.parse(localStorage?.getItem('token')) || {};
      if (token) {
        config.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${token}`;
      }
      // config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json';
      return config;
    },
    (error) => {
      Promise.reject(error);
    },
  );

  this.api.addMonitor(this.tokenMonitor);
}

private tokenMonitor(response: any) {
  const { ok, status } = response;

  if (!ok && status !== 200) {
    // I should do redirect here
    localStorage.removeItem('user');
  }
}
```

I hope this is helpful.

Comment: This is good, I believe it would be better if we only pass the token for the requests which need it. right now, it seems to me we add it to all the requests, and based on the response, we remove it?